# Independent and dependent events

Tags: probability

Suppose that $A,B,C$ are three events such that $A$ and $B$ are independent but $A$ and $C$ are dependent. Can anything be said about the independence of $B$ and $C$? Intuitively, I would think that $B$ and $C$ are dependent, too, but I was unable to prove that.

Comment: "I would think that $B$ and $C$ are dependent". No, for instance let $A=C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be dependent, but they don't have to be.

You're drawing a card out of a deck

A - you draw a black card
B - you draw an ace
C - you draw a spade

Here B and C are independent

A - you draw a black card
B - you draw an ace
C - you draw the ace of spades

Here B and C are dependent